# how to keep the datetime format from csv to mysql database when importing data?

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I have a csv file where I changed the initial datetime format:

- from `m/d/yyyy h:mm (6/15/2011  5:26:00 PM)`
- to   `yyyy-dd-mm h:mm (2011-15-06 17:26)`

This was done in order to avoid `0000-00-00` as datetime value in MySQL database when importing data from that csv to MySQL.

This did not fix the problem. I still found `0000-00-00` as datetime value in my database.

To fix the problem, I first created the database in mysql (before importing the data from the csv file),  and I used Datetime type in order to keep the values of date and time from that csv file.

Did I forget something? or is there any better way to fix that problem?

Comment: what is the actual SQL query that you are giving the database?

Comment: oops! sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using phpMyAdmin to import the data from csv file to mysql database.

Comment: do you have date in csv closed in quotes?

Comment: no, I don't have any date in csv closed in quotes. The csv was obtained by saving data from a database in mysql. Now, i am trying to import those data in a different database. everything else is correctly imported except the date and time.

Comment: Can you not identify the row that's importing as 0000-00-00 from some other field, and then look to see what the date in your CSV file is?

Comment: each row contains a date and time when the record was saved. once imported to mysql, each record has 0000-00-00 as value for date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having this problem because you aren't putting your dates in quotes.  This won't work

```
INSERT INTO some_table 2011-07-12;
```

but this will

```
INSERT INTO some_table "2011-07-12";
```

Try editing one of the rows in your CSV file to put the date in quotes and see if that one gets read in properly.

Answer (score 0):

try change day/month `2011-15-06---->2011-06-15` ;)
and look at zeros may be it `00-00-0000` not `0000-00-00`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
you can change the date format in the csv to format '2005-03-15' as shown in above image. Also, in the database table use 'date' or 'datetime' (based on requirement). On  file import, you should see correct datetime field.

[image]

This should solve this issue.